# mysql | Conditional query from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**questions**

```
id title
1  First question
2  Second question
3  Third question
```

**answers**

```
id   text    question_id
1    Answer1 1
2    Answer2 1
3    Answer3 2
```

I'm searching for the query to return unaswered questions (Question id:3 in the example above)? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select id, title from question A Left Join answer B on A.id=B.question_id where B.question_id  is null
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mysql does not support MINUS (or at least I'm not aware of) you have to use join

```
SELECT q.id
FROM questions q LEFT JOIN answers a
ON q.id = a.question_id
WHERE a.question_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,title from questions where id NOT IN(select distinct(question_id) from answers)
```

NOT IN in mysql will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from questions left outer join answers on questions.id = question_id
where question_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

`select q.id,q.title from questions q where q.id NOT IN(select distinct(question_id) from answers)`

not in use is safe query to find answered question.